# Batch process list

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to get process list in cmd/batch like in ctrl+alt+del/ctrl+shift+esc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few ways:

You can use `tasklist`, `wmic process list` (on most Windows machines), or `get-process` if you are using Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another one, the excellent [PsList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682) program from SysInternals.

Answer (score 1):

Try `tasklist`.

See documentation here: http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `tasklist`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `taskmgr.exe`, `call taskmgr.exe`, `start taskmgr.exe`, etc, to open task manager.